# How to provide separate voltages from a common power source

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

Assuming the input voltage is regulated, how do I provide two different, specific voltages to the below devices? I specifically want 4[V] in the left part and 3[V] in the right part of the parallel sub-circuit on the right.

I thought a voltage-divider circuit would help me get 4[V] after the first resistor, but all the components in the middle have got me doubting myself.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqPMIk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

The devices are an analog temperature sensor (such as LM35) with an operating voltage in the rage 4~35[V], and a microcontroller, with an operating voltage in the range 2~4[V]. The sensor output is to be connected to one of the pins of the microcontroller. The sensor is on the left and the controller is on the right.

Comment: Use more voltage regulators or ask a less generic question.

Comment: @Andyaka multiple regulators huh? Didn't occur to me I could do that.

Comment: I agree with Andy aka; use multiple voltage regulators. We can't give much help based only on voltage. You would need to tell us much more about the devices, e.g. how much current each device needs, if the current varies, the range of operating voltages, etc. That 'voltage divider' *might* appear to produce the correct voltages but only for small, and constant, current consumption. Much better to use an active device like a voltage regulator for each voltage. You need to be careful that the voltage regulators you choose have a small enough drop-out-voltage, e.g. 78xx need 2V, so no good for 4V

Comment: One of the main assumption on using voltage divider is that no current is drawn from the output. This explains why using one to power a device (which will draw some current) usually never works.

Comment: @gbulmer I didn't think it was too important, but the devices are an analog temperature sensor (think: LM35) and a microcontroller. The sensor output is to be connected to one of the IO pins of the microcontroller. The operating voltage of the sensor was about 4~35[V] and the microcontroller between 2~4[V]. I was thinking of using a DC-to-DC converter for the input voltage, which would be powered by batteries. Is that safe enough, or do I have to encapsulate the power supply of each device by regulators?

Comment: @Edesign it sounds like a voltage divider isn't usable in The Real World.

Comment: Please update your question with that extra information so that the community is 'on the same page'; please don't leave critical information in comments. Which microcontroller? A voltage divider is okay to set a reference voltage or for constant currents, but not something which will vary its current like those devices.

Comment: @Adam Jansen Voltage dividers are very useful to sense voltages. For example, you if you want to measure the voltage of a signal going from 0V to 10V with an ADC which is only capable of measuring between 0V and 5V, you will use a voltage divider to divide the input by 2. This works because the ADC is not drawing any current on its pins used to sense the voltage. However, it will be powered from another pin, which will probably connected to a voltage regulator.

Comment: @gbulmer & Edesign thanks. I guess I will use regulators in parallel to power the sensor and controller. Then voltage divider on the sensor output if necessary. So if my regulators give me 5[V], I should just use resistors under them to get to my desired voltages, right? (anyone want to answer this question or should I delete?)

Comment: I am getting confused.  I don't understand why you are asking about using resistors to reach a voltage. That only works for a load that takes practically no current e.g. ADC, or a constant current. Tell us exactly what devices you are using, then we can probably answer your question. AFAICT, something like a LM35 temperature sensor is an active device, and not a constant current load, and a microcontroller is very far from a constant current load. Neither of those loads should have a resistor between them and a voltage regulator. Are you maybe suffering an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: @gbulmer Well if the regulator gives 5[V] and the microcontroller only takes up to ~4[V], I would assume I can't use the regulator's output without a resistor.

Comment: We'll probably go round in circles here until you describe what you are trying to do. **DO NOT EVER** step down a voltage, i.e. 5V to 4V, with a resistor for a load which varies its current consumption like a microcontroller. Use a voltage regulator which gives the voltage the microcontroller needs, probably 3.3V. I repeat, if you tell us the devices you intend to use, the community can probably answer your question. I now feel like I have explained this enough times and you still haven't got it. Maybe I am not being clear enough, someone else can try.

Comment: @gbulmer thank you again. I'm not clear on the *why* I shouldn't ever step down a voltage, even when the voltage is regulated, but I will have to ask that in another question.

Comment: @gbulmer oh and just to be clear, when I wrote "anyone want to answer this question" I meant post an answer to the original question, because as far as I was concerned, you had already answered the question in comments. The rest, while really helpful, is superfluous for this one question IMHO. I might come back and ask another question to clear up some misunderstandings on my part.

Comment: Okay, I have tried to get you to ask the full question, but for some reason you won't. Here is my view. To not to understand why we don't step down the voltage from a voltage regulator with a resistor for an active device like a microcontroller (which varies its current rapidly and significantly) suggests a lack of understanding of Ohm's law. Without understanding Ohm's law, it will be very hard to get electronics to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44138/discussion-between-adam-jensen-and-gbulmer).

Comment: Thanks for the invitation, however there is no point, you've accepted an answer. As a hint, try to calculate the resistor value needed to drop 5V to 4V. Assume the current consumption of the microcontroller could vary by a factor of 50x, say 0.1mA to 5mA.

Comment: @gbulmer ok then, from chat: "RE: "DO NOT EVER step down a voltage, i.e. 5V to 4V, with a resistor for a load which varies its current consumption like a microcontroller". I just mentally went back to the drawing board, and realized I couldn't even pick a suitable resistor to step down the voltage from 5 to 4[V] because the current is unknown. But your wording there makes it sound like it is possible. Am I misreading your comment?"

Comment: I am not a fan of chat if questions and answers seem generally useful. So I have posted an answer which hopefully covers all of your questions. This was partly motivated by the answer you have accepted which IMHO is somewhat misleading in several areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your question is not very precise, and according to the few pieces of information you gave in the comments, I will assume:

- You need to lower the voltage to 4V and 3V to supply the main POWER of 2 devices
- The left device is a sensor, which requires a power supply of 4V
- The right device is a microcontroller, which requires a power supply of 3.3V (common voltage for a microcontroller, but if you really want 3V, you can adapt my answer with 3V)

As we only talk about powering devices, any voltage divider won't work properly, whatever the values used for the input voltage or the resistor. This is because one of the main assumption of a voltage divider is to have no current at the output. This is not the case here, as both the microcontroller and the sensor are consuming current: they are considered as "loads" for the circuit.

As explained in the comments, the solution is to use voltage regulators. But, because you need 2 different voltages, you will need 2 different regulators: one with an output of 4V, to power your sensor, and a second one with an output of 3.3V (or 3V), to power the microcontroller. The 2 regulators input can be connected to the same main power source, which could be a battery, for example.

This brings us to the second advantage of a power regulator: they can accept a large range of input voltage (with limits given in the Datasheet), and the output voltage will always be regulated at the same value. When using a battery, let say a 2 cells lithium ion, the output voltage is not constant. It will vary between about 6V, when discharged, to around 8.4V when fully charged. Using a regulator will allow you to run your devices whatever the battery charge.

Note: there are few cases where you could use resistors to lower the voltage for a power supply. However, I would not recommend to do so in your case, as it requires a good understanding of the behaviour of your loads to ensure the power supply voltage will always be within the limits they can tolerate whatever the situation.

Comment: Good answer, although your voltages aren't right for a 4S Li-Ion

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thanks for the remark. I updated the voltages for the Li-Ion battery.

Comment: @gbulmer did you mean to write you agree that a voltage *regulator* is a better solution?

Comment: @gbulmer I know the answer is doing some shortcuts on the theory. But I think it delivers a clear message: if you're a beginner in electronics and you need to power a device such as a microcontroller, don't use a simple voltage divider! Once you get older, and you know more about electronics, you might be able to use resistors in some particular cases. Actually, the idea of using diodes you gave in your answer is a very good one if you don't need an accurate voltage regulation.

Comment: @AdamJensen - YES. I apologise for causing confusion.  I will delete my comment above and tack it on here to avoid confusion. *Correction of earlier comment*: The answer is incorrect about a voltage divider, it doesn't rely on a load which takes 'no current', and could be used to power a circuit; see my answer. I do agree that a *voltage regulator* is a much better solution than a *voltage divider* for several reasons.

Comment: If you added a small note at the end I'd be happier. I agree fully that voltage regulators are better. However it is *possible* to use a voltage divider, or just a resistor drop, to provide power to an electronic circuit. Please, by all means, add any caveats you feel helpful.

Comment: @gbulmer Note added :)

Answer (score 1):

In a *general case*, it *may* be practical to use a single resistor to step down a voltage to power some electronics.

As I wrote in comments, for that to work, the load presented by the electronics (to be powered) should be pretty much *constant*, i.e. a simple resistive load.

This clearly works when we consider Ohm's Law. By adjusting the values and ratio of resistors, it's possible to get almost any voltage and current through the resistors in a voltage divider. Hence, for a simple resistive load it is feasible to drop voltage and power for that load by dropping voltage across an 'upper' resistor. Of course, the resistors will be dissipating power as heat, so they will need to be rated to dissipate that power.

It doesn't make much sense, but if a constant resistance load is in parallel with a 'lower' resistor, then *all* resistors needs to be included in the 'voltage divider calculation'. No magic, it 'just works'.

**Summary**: a voltage divider, derived from calculations, work for a *constant* load. As long as *all* resistances are included in the calculations, it doesn't matter as long as a circuit is a *constant* load on the voltage divider, its effect just needs to be factored into the calculation.

However, when the load presented varies in current consumption, it is effectively varying its resistance. For the voltage drop across the 'upper' resistor to stay constant, the 'upper' resistor *must* vary when the 'lower' resistor varies. I.e. it would only be possible to keep the *voltage* across the lower resistor constant when it varies by varying the resistance of the upper resistor. That is a model for how a voltage regulator works.

**Summary**: The voltage drop across a varying load resistance (something with a varying current consumption) can only be kept constant by the the 'upper resistor' by dynamically varying its resistance i.e. maintaning a constant voltage drop. That is an active device like a diode, transistor or more complex electronics, not a dumb resistor.

In this specific case, the load is a microcontroller. That is far from a constant resistive load. Read the datasheet for the microcontroller and it should be clear that it varies significantly; typically it varies as it boots, and may vary even more depending on the peripherals that are switched on or off.

It may be practically impossible to determine the range of current consumption to even begin to do the feasibility calculations without very sophisticated test equipment. Further, why bother? Active ways of dropping voltage are simple to use and reliable. Providing a linear regulators drop-out voltage is well below 5V-Vout (I'd aim for a headroom of 100%) then it will 'just work'.

**Summary**: Dropping voltage across a fixed resistor will be practically impossible for an active, current varying load like a microcontroller. A voltage regulator (Linear or DC-DC switching) is a good technology to derive a specific voltage to power electronics, and as Edesign explains has significant advantages.

Side note: The voltage for a dynamically changing load *could* be provided using a voltage divider. However, the current variation through the dynamic load needs to be small compared to the load through the voltage divider in order to maintain voltage within tolerance. This is Ohm's Law in action.

As a concrete example: assume the dynamic load of the unknown-microcontroller varies from 0.2mA to 20mA, and needs the voltage maintained within 10%. So, as long as the current through a voltage divider is more than 10x bigger than 20mA, i.e. over 200mA, then the effect of the dynamically changing load will not push the voltage, across the voltage divider, outside of acceptable limits.

Also note, the mid-point voltage driving the microcontroller will 'bounce around' as the dynamic load of the unknown-microcontroller varies. This will make a poor reference voltage for an ADC.

Summary: it is possible to maintain the voltage across a dynamically varying load within a reasonable tolerance using a voltage divider. However, the current through the voltage divider needs to be *much* bigger than through the dynamic load. Further, all of the power, over 90% in this example, is wasted as heat. Hence a voltage regulator wins by wasting much less power, and so might be 20x or more efficient. This makes very little sense compared to a voltage regulator. Further, the voltage across the dynamic load *will* vary, and hence may be useless as a voltage reference for an ADC, requiring more complexity to provide a constant voltage reference.

If, for some reason, you can't use a voltage regulator to drop voltage, then an alternative is to use one of more diodes. For a relatively wide current range, diodes do give a (relatively) constant voltage drop. So you could drop 5V to reach between 3V and 4V with two diodes in series.

AFAIK, something like an LM35 is an active device, it hasn't got a constant current consumption. However, it can operate at a wide voltage range, probably over 5V. So don't drop any voltage; drive it directly from the 5V.

Connect the output of the LM35-like-device to the input of the unknown-microcontroller by driving the top of a voltage divider. That will allow the LM35-like-device to rise to 5V, while restricting its range to a safe operating voltage of the unknown-microcontroller's input.

As Edesign has explained, it is practical to drive the input of an ADC via a voltage divider to step the LM35-like-device output voltage down.

However, the point is *not* that an ADC is a small load. The input impedance of the ADC is practically constant, so its affect on the voltage divider will be constant, it will look like a fixed resistor in parallel with the 'lower' resistor of the voltage divider.

Typically, an ADC does need a driving source capable of a big fraction of a milliamp or more to drive its sampling circuit. For example, STM32F1 are capable of sampling at 1msps, but need the driving impedance about 0.4k. So check the spec. for the unknown-microcontroller. As an example, a voltage divider to drop from 5V to 3V might use a 220 and 330 ohm resistor. An LM35 is capable of driving that voltage divider, but check the LM35-like-device.

**Summary**: an ADC does take current to drive it, it *does* load a voltage divider. However, an ADC input is a *constant* load, so the voltage divider will work consistently. Further, the input of an ADC may need milliamps to function at its rated speed, so the voltage divider calculation is affected.

**Overall**:

1. Use a voltage regulator (with enough drop-out voltage headroom) to drop 5V
   down to 3V/3.3V for the unknown-microcontroller.
2. Drive the LM35-like-device directly from 5V; stepping 5V down to 4V
   is unlikely to be useful.
3. Use a voltage divider to convert the 5V maximum output of the
   LM35-like-device to the ADC input range of the
   unknown-microcontroller.
4. Ensure the load of the ADC is driven with enough current, through
   the voltage divider, to satisfy the ADC's specification. This may require
   relatively low value resistors, and not just resistors in the correct ratio.